# Can you force classes inheriting from abstract base class to only have the public methods defined in base case?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, abstract-class

Is it possible to have an abstract class but FORCE implementing classes to have only the public methods that are in the abstract class?

I don't care how the private methods work, but I want to force the classes to have only one public method.

For example, say I have the following abstract class:

```
class MyObjectTransform
{
    public:
    virtual ~MyObjectTransform()
    {
    }

    virtual MyObject transform(MyObject input) = 0;
};
```

Then I want to force all objects inheriting from `MyObjectTransform` to ONLY have a single (other than the constructor) public method, `transform`. I don't care what private methods the inheriting classes have. Is this possible?

**Update:**
The goal here is to force the developer to only expose functionality through a single method. For example, consider this situation:

```
class ATransform
{
private:
        MyObject A_Stuff(MyObject input);

public:
    override MyObject transform(MyObject input)
    {
        return this->A_stuff(input);
    }
};

class BTransform
{
public:
    MyObject B_Stuff(MyObject input);

    override MyObject transform(MyObject input)
    {
        return this->B_stuff(input);
    }
};
```

The problem here is that the dev can call `B_Stuff`directly. I want to prevent this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Even if you could do this, it wouldn't force developers to only expose the class's functionality through that one method (and that's a really weird goal, too).

Comment: I don't understand. If I could do this how  could a developer expose functionality any other way if the child classes could only have a single public method?

Comment: This idea goes against the whole inheritance/reusability concept. I can imagine using nested private class could achieve something similar to what you want but unless you clearly specify your motivation for this, we can barely help.

Comment: Friend declarations.

Comment: Btw, C++ calls methods "member functions".

Comment: @Alegnem: Actually, this idea enforces the concept. One could say the OP intuitively strives for a stricter separation of interface (public functions) and implementation (virtual functions).

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Exactly. I want to enforce this separation on a stricter level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already using the mechanism that is in place for this scenario: it's the abstract base class!

The whole point of it is that all classes in this hierarchy are meant to support being used polymorphically through a pointer/reference to the base class `MyObjectTransform`. This way the user does not know what public methods the implementing class has because he can only use the one available through the base class: `transform`.

If you want to enforce this slightly more strictly, don't expose the declaration of the implementing classes in a header at all. Hide `BTransform` and `ATransform`, and expose only factory functions along with the abstract base class.

```
std::unique_ptr<MyObjectTransform> makeATransform()
{
    return { new ATransform };
}

std::unique_ptr<MyObjectTransform> makeBTransform()
{
    return { new BTransform };
}
```

This way the client/developer code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    auto btransform = makeBTransform();

    btransform->B_Stuff(input);   // ERROR, MyObjectTransform doesn't have this member function.
    btransform->transform(input); // FINE
}
```

Users can only use the one public method in the base class.

Ofcourse someone could cast the pointer to a `BTransform*`, and then do anything they want (provided they could find out what the actual implementation of `BTransform` is, since we hid it). But then theres no bypassing the fact that to prevent `public` methods from being accessible you have to make them `private`, like chmike wrote. As Herb Sutter said:

> C++ protects against Murphy, not Machiavelli

Answer (score 5):

No you can't. Derived classes can define any public member functions they want. There is no way to put a constraint on that.

**Update**:

Declare B_Stuff as *private* if you don't want that users access it. Declare it as *protected* if you want that classes derived from BTransform can also use it.

```
class BTransform
{
private:
    MyObject B_Stuff(MyObject input);

Public:     
    override MyObject transform(MyObject input)
    {
        return this->B_stuff(input);
    }
};
```

But you can't force with the C++ language to declare B_Stuff as private or protected. It must be defined as a policy.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, **public functions should be non-virtual and virtual functions should be private** (with the exception of the destructor). Applying this [guideline](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) makes your problem disappear entirely, because there is only one public function left for clients of the class to call:

```
class MyObjectTransform
{
    public:
    virtual ~MyObjectTransform()
    {
    }

    MyObject transform(MyObject input) // non-virtual!
    {
        // can do extra stuff, e.g. check input for validity
        doTransform(input);
    }

    private:
    virtual MyObject doTransform(MyObject input) = 0;
};

class ATransform : public MyObjectTransform
{
private:
    MyObject A_Stuff(MyObject input);

     MyObject doTransform(MyObject input) override
    {
        return this->A_Stuff(input);
    }
};

class BTransform : public MyObjectTransform
{
private:
    MyObject B_Stuff(MyObject input);

    MyObject doTransform(MyObject input) override
    {
        return this->B_Stuff(input);
    }
};
```